# Org-Mode How to position tables correctly when exporting to Latex?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-table

I have a document I have written in org-mode which contains several tables.
The tables all have the following attributes.

```
#+begin_table
#+LATEX: \caption{Initial risk List}
#+LATEX: \label{tab:risk-list}
#+LATEX: \centering
#+LATEX: \adjustbox{max width=\textwidth}{
#+ATTR_LATEX: :center t :placement [h]
|Col1|Col2|
|----+----|
| 1  | 2  |
|----+----|
#+end_table
```

The configuration is to allow my tables to scale correctly for my document without running off the page which works, however, the `[h]` argument isn't being read by LaTeX as all the tables get places on one page together in the pdf document instead of being at their positions in the text where I want them. Am I passing the wrong latex configuration or is it just not picking it up during the parsing? I am using spacemacs by the way I'm not sure if that changes anything.

After looking at the tex file org produced it seems there is no placement values put into the document.

Comment: Does [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned) help? Basically, don't use `[h]`, use `[!htbp]`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! But unfortunately it did not

Comment: I was using the `table` environment to keep the adjust box contained to just the table

Comment: I don't know how `\adjustbox` works, but it seems not the like the `center` environment that org-export generates around the `tabular`. There is also a syntax error: you need add a closing brace to close the `\adjustbox` argument (and of course you need to `\usepackage{adjustbox}` somehow, but I imagine that's been done).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking at the problem for a while I found this solution.

```
 #+LATEX: \begin{adjustbox}{width={\textwidth},keepaspectratio}
 #+ATTR_LATEX: :placement [!h]  
 #+LATEX: \centering
|Col1|Col2|
|----+----|
| 1  | 2  |
|----+----|
#+LATEX: \end{adjustbox}
```

While also including

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{adjustbox}
```

At the top of the document.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to header:

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{float}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \restylefloat{table}
```

And then write your tables like this:

```
#+CAPTION: ML Algorithms
#+NAME: ml-algos-table
#+ATTR_LATEX: :center t :placement [H]
|----+----|
|Col1|Col2|
|----+----|
| 1  | 2  |
|----+----|
```

Also refer [this](http://gada.space/blog/posts/org-mode-tables/) and [this](https://orgmode.org/manual/Tables-in-LaTeX-export.html)